# How do I create a Go type derived from string that matches a pattern?

Tags: go, types

I'm trying to create a new Go type that's based on `string` but is required to match a pattern (Slack username, e.g. `@ben`).

When used, the type would look something like:

```
var user SlackUser
user = SlackUser("@ben")

fmt.Println(user) //This should print: @ben
```

If it matches the pattern, `NewSlackUser` will work. If it doesn't, it will throw an error.

The pattern to match, which is based on [this](https://gist.github.com/gswalden/27ac96e497c3aa1f3230), is:

`^@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._-]*$`

(I'm very new to Go, so any correction to my approach is much appreciated)

Comment: See https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Answer (score 4):

Use a struct type:

```
type SlackUser struct {
    username string
}
```

Compile the regular expression:

```
var (
    pattern = regexp.MustCompile("^@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9._-]*$")
)
```

Constructor:

```
func NewSlackUser(username string) (*SlackUser, error) {
    if !pattern.MatchString(username) {
        return nil, errors.New("Invalid username.")
    }
    return &SlackUser{ username }, nil
}
```

Stringer:

```
func (s *SlackUser) String() string {
    return s.username
}
```

Full [example](https://play.golang.org/p/pGLHsTcSyU)